# How to test WebSocket component on client side?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, websocket, jasmine, karma-jasmine

There is an App build with Grunt. While building, Karma runs some unit-tests for client, using Phantom JS.

There is a new component, working with server via WebSocket. And i need to cover it with some tests. Then working with Ajax, everything is much more clear. There is a description how to do ajax-tests in Jasmine tutorial. But i have no idea there to start with WebSocket testing.

How did you solved this problem? How should i write and run this tests?